# Is there a way to trigger Territory Assignment Rules from Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

As the question states, does anybody know of a way to kick off the territory assignment process programatically so that it can be run when an account moves from one location to another via a trigger?

Our client has person accounts moving on a regular basis and find running the process manually each time rather tedious.

I've posted this question as a sample on my salesforce stack exchange proposal too, please join the effort: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce

Comment: Have been pointed towards this boards post: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Assigning-Territories-through-APEX-without-Assignment-Rules/td-p/170417

Comment: Wish I could help you on this Lacey but I've only handled this type of functionality through completely custom code - not the standard territory assignment feature.

Comment: Seems like a definite no.  I would have assumed you could use the assignment rule header for Database.DMLOptions, but the docs specifically state that it works for leads and cases, but not accounts or territory management.

Comment: I have an answer to this question..may be some one looking for solution .. Please take a look this ans http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/107579/18731